# Arbitrary matrix dimension in matrix class

Tags: c++, class, matrix

The task is as follows: Describe the class "matrix of numbers" with component data: the dimensions of the matrix, a pointer to the elements. Overload operations: << (matrix output to the screen), + (addition of matrices), unary ¬– (change the sign of each element), / = (divide each element by a number). I performed it, and performed it correctly, but you need to set the matrix dimension from the keyboard, and as you can see, it is set in advance for me [3] [3]. It sounds pretty simple, but something I'm really dumb. Thanks in advance for your help. Here is the code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix()
    {
        int Table[3][3];
    }
    int Table[3][3];
    void Create()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                Table[i][j] = 10;
    }
};
ostream& operator <<(ostream& t, Matrix a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            t << a.Table[i][j] << " ";
        t << "\n";
    }
    return t;
}
Matrix& operator /=(Matrix& a, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a.Table[i][j] /= num;
    return a;
}
Matrix& operator -(Matrix& a, int empty)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a.Table[i][j] = -a.Table[i][j];
    return a;
}
Matrix& operator +(Matrix& a, Matrix b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            a.Table[i][j] += b.Table[i][j];
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    int u;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Matrix Example;
    Example.Create();
    Matrix Example1;
    Example1.Create();


    cout << Example;

    cout << Example1;
    cout << "Сумма матриц: "<<endl;
    cout << Example + Example1;

                Example - 1;

                Example1 - 1;


cout<< Example + Example1;

            cout << "На сколько вы хотите её поделить?\n";
            cin >> u;

                Example /= u;

                Example1 /= u;
                cout << Example;

                cout << Example1;


}`
```

Comment: Searching for "dynamic 2d array" should find you what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dynamically create the matrix. 
In order to this you need to use pointers(*). Change int table[3][3]
    double table**;

An example of how it could be implemented (note that I use matrix instead of table)

```
class Matrix {
private:
    double** matrix;
    int col;
    int row;
public:
    Matrix(){};
    void Create(int row, int col);
};


void Matrix::Create(int row_, int col_){

    double val = 0.0;
    col = col_; // initalize private members
    row = row_;

    matrix = new double*[row]; // Create a new array of size row_

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[col]; // Create new cols of size col (inside array of row)
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = val;
            val = val + 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to reuse your design for simplicity, but I really suggest that you try to specify the dimensions of the matrix in a constructor instead and maybe even construct the matrix in it as well.
Something like this:

```
Matrix(int row_, int col_) : row(row_), col(col_) {*/ create matrix here /*};
```

You can skip the "create matrix here" part and use your own Create() if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic memory allocation for that. I won't fiddle around with pointers (new / delete) unless you are explicitly told to. As a beginner you should probably use the standard template library (STL) tools:

`#include <vector>` and use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> Table` instead of `int Table[3][3]`. Then write a constructor like this:

```cpp
Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols)
{
    Table.resize(rows);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Table.size(); ++i)
        Table[i].resize(cols);
}
```

You can additionally store the dimension of the matrix, but there is no need to do it since you can get the information from the vectors. Replace the hardcoded dimensions in all loops by the corresponding dynamic sizes (stored or extracted from the vectors). For example:

```cpp
Matrix& operator +(Matrix& a, Matrix b)
{
    unsigned int rows = a.Table.size();
    unsigned int cols = a.Table[0].size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            a.Table[i][j] += b.Table[i][j];
    return a;
}
```

However, this vector of vectors is not really effective. Better would be a single vector but I guess for a beginner it is okay.

Greetings